# Average some rows of many of the same measure

Tags: r

I have a table (below). I want to average measures 2 and 3 for years 2007, 2008, and 2009 for each meter number. Then I want to disregard or remove the remaining years:

```
MeterNo year    measure 2   measure 3
a   2005    5   8
a   2006    10  6
a   2007    5   7
a   2008    4   2
a   2009    2   2
b   2005    4   6
b   2006    8   1
b   2007    2   7
b   2008    10  1
b   2009    1   1
c   2005    3   0
c   2006    10  4
c   2007    7   3
c   2008    7   2
c   2009    9   1
d   2005    8   0
d   2006    6   3
d   2007    9   6
d   2008    1   8
d   2009    2   2
```

Any help is appreciated; I'm having trouble translating what I want to do into commands.

Comment: `transform(subset(your.data.frame, year %in% 2007:2009), avg = mean(c(measure2, measure3)))`?

Answer (score 0):

Below, I provide a `dplyr` method for doing this. Hopefully somebody will also show you a base `R` way to round it all out.

First , I create some fake data that is similar to your data structure.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(MeterNo = sample(c(LETTERS[1:3]), 100, replace=TRUE),
                 Year = sample(c(2005:2009),100,replace=TRUE),
                 measure2 = runif(100), measure3=runif(100))

df$newMeasure <- rowMeans(df[,c('measure2','measure3')])
```

Now I have a `data.frame` with 5 columns. The code below does the following: I first group the data based on year and meter number. Then I calculate the per-group mean of the means of `measure2` and `measure3` as calculated above (called `newMeasure`). After that, I disregard all years not equal to 2007, 2008, or 2009.

```
df %>%
  group_by(Year, MeterNo) %>%
  summarize(mean(newMeasure)) %>%
  filter(Year %in% c(2007:2009))
```

There are definitely other ways to do this same procedure. It sounds a tiny bit like a homework problem, but I'm not going to jump to any conclusions. ;)